# How to run real-time javascript inside of an existing Chrome window?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

Planning a desktop application that allows users to highlight text, press a keyboard command and have it copy the text and input it into an HTML element in a webpage.
This would need to be running in the existing Chrome window, not a virtual browser.
How can we run JavaScript in real-time in the browser without using the terminal? It needs to run on a keyboard input.

Comment: I'm gonna swear now: `eval()`.

Comment: Have you looked into [`Chrome.ahk`](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=42890)?